# Interior of the sum of two sets?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

Is it always true for two subsets $A $ and $B$ of a real Hilbert space $H$ that
$\operatorname{int}(A+B)=\operatorname{int}(A)+\operatorname{int}(B)$ ?

Comment: No, generally you don't have equality. You have an inclusion, $\operatorname{int} (A) + \operatorname{int} (B) \subset \operatorname{int} (A+B)$, and in general, that is a proper inclusion.

Comment: You can easily have $int(A)=int(B)=\emptyset$, while $int(A+B)$ is nonempty.

Comment: Thanks. However, it always holds that $int(cl(A))=int(A)$. Right?

Comment: No.  Let $A=\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$, then $\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(A))=(0,1)$ while $\operatorname{int}(A)=\emptyset$.

Comment: What if the set is convex? Is that true?

Comment: Even a convex set can have empty interior and be dense if the space is infinite-dimensional. The kernel of a discontinuous linear form is a dense hyperplane. As a hyperplane, it's convex, since it's a proper linear subspace it has empty interior, and since the linear form is discontinuous, it's not closed, hence dense.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't. For example if you take for $A=B$ the set of irrational numbers in ${\bf R}$, then $A+B=\overline{A}={\bf R}$, even though $\operatorname{int}(A)=\emptyset$.

In general, in any nontrivial, separable Hilbert space $H$,  if you pick a countable dense subset $C$, then if you take $A=B=H\setminus C$ (the complement), you will have $\operatorname{cl}(A)=A+B=H$.

If $A,B\subseteq H$ are convex and dimension of $H$ is less than two, then this is true (convex sets in $1$-dimensional space are open, up to a point or two). Otherwise, it fails again, since you can take for $A$ a $1$-dimensional subspace and $B$ a complementary subspace.

If the dimension is $\aleph_0$, you can take for $A$ the span of a countable dense subset, and it will have empty interior, though of course the closure will be everything.

If $H$ is finite-dimensional, then we do indeed have $\operatorname{int}\overline A=\operatorname{int} A$. To do this, you can, for example, show that if $A$ is contained in some cone, then so is $\overline A$ (and then notice that a point is in the interior of a convex set $A$ iff $A$ is not contained in any cone with vertex at this point).

With a little more care, you can find counterexamples in arbitrary infinite-dimensional Banach spaces.